# Primefaces - PDF file with <p:media> not displayed

Tags: primefaces

I am using PF 6.2 trying to display pfd files, as treamedContent, dynamically read from disk with p:media in an ui:repeat. I made thes observations:

- getStreamedContent method is called 3 times when p:media is in
  ui:repeat and nothing is displayed
- getStreamedContent method is called 4 times when p:media is out of
  ui:repeat and the object generate doesn't content full url of
  resource

  data="/indexing/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2&pfdrid=a8336291b4933a59ef33ecd37b1d4a33&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=2270ce03-84be-4e82-9621-48b6030e7141">
   . When prefixing the content of data property with localhost:8080 ,
  the pdf file is generated.

this is my files content

```
<ui:repeat var="file" value="#{batchDetailController.batchContentMetaDatas}">
     <p:media value="#{file.streamFile}" player="pdf" cache="false" /></ui:repeat>
```

bean in session scope:

```
public DefaultStreamedContent getStreamFile() {
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
          return new DefaultStreamedContent();}
  else {
       byte[] buffer = loadFile(filePath); //filePath content the absolute path of pdf file
       return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer), "application/pdf");
   }
}
```

Any help will be greatfull.

Comment: As suggested on the forums `p:media` is unreliable with PDF because the browers change so often i suggest using PrimeFaces Extensions Document Viewer: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf

Comment: @Melloware thank you for your reply. I just added PFE and still not have document display. The getStreamedContent  method is called twice and current phase is always equal to PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE.

Comment: @KJ i don't really understant the process you described according to what i al doing. Please can you be more explicit.